# Concatenar string com inteiro

Tags: c, string, int

Tenho uma variável que é um vetor de char, e nesse vetor eu preciso inserir um número que é um inteiro, buscando ele de outra variável:

```
int quantidade;
char id[3] = 'p';
```

Por exemplo, se a quantidade for 2, preciso que a string id fique com "p2". Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da pra você utilizar o [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) como truque pra formatar seus dados, fique atento aos parâmetros dele:

1. o *buffer* onde vai guardar o retorno da função com a nova formatação.

2. o tamanho do buffer pra ser escrito

3. a formatação da string, igual é usado no `printf()`

4. seus parâmetros que vão ser adicionados na formatação

```
int quantidade = 2;
char id[3] = "p";
char novoId[10];

snprintf (novoId, 10, "%s%d", id, quantidade );
printf("%s", novoId);
```

> p2

Dessa forma não tem problema se for um número maior que 9, que ele vai formatar corretamente.

### [IdeOne Exemplo](https://ideone.com/aWmzsD)

Comment: usando o sprintf não fica mais simples? não tem a necessidade de ciar outra string.

Comment: @Mathi901 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315936/which-of-sprintf-snprintf-is-more-secure